# Looking for a book about a slave that gathers friends and goes into a desert to find a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this book back in late 90's. It is about a slave that gathers some friends and goes into a desert to find/fight a dragon. There is also a revolt/uprising in the slaves' home town. I can't remember if this is a single book or a trilogy.

I think the rulers were called Sorcerer-lords or Sorcerer-Kings. And I remember one character was called Boris or Borys.

Comment: Up until Sorceror-stuff it sounded a bit like the [Pit Dragon Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy) by Jane Yolen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the Dark Sun D&D setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Sun), Borys is the name of the first Athasian dragon who was the Sorcerer-King of Ur-Draxa.  There are [about a dozen novels set on Athas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dark_Sun_novels); the entire world is a desert and slaves are a constant of the setting so it's difficult to narrow it down to one in particular, but it's almost certainly one of these.

**Prism Pentad - Troy Denning**

- The Verdant Passage (October 1991), (ISBN 1-56076-121-0)
- The Crimson Legion (April 1992), (ISBN 1-56076-260-8)
- The Amber Enchantress (October 1992), (ISBN 1-56076-236-5)
- The Obsidian Oracle (June 1993), (ISBN 1-56076-603-4)
- The Cerulean Storm (September 1993), (ISBN 1-56076-642-5)

**Tribe of One - Simon Hawke**

- The Outcast (November 1993), (ISBN 1-56076-676-X)
- The Seeker (April 1994), (ISBN 1-56076-701-4)
- The Nomad (October 1994), (ISBN 1-56076-702-2)

**Chronicles of Athas - Various Authors**

- The Brazen Gambit (July 1994), by Lynn Abbey (ISBN 1-56076-872-X)
- The Darkness Before the Dawn (February 1995), by Ryan Hughes (ISBN
  0-7869-0104-7)
- The Broken Blade (May 1995), by Simon Hawke (ISBN 0-7869-0137-3)
- Cinnabar Shadows (July 1995), by Lynn Abbey (ISBN 0-7869-0181-0)
- The Rise & Fall of a Dragon King (April 1996), by Lynn Abbey (ISBN
  0-7869-0476-3)

Comment: +1 It's the Prism Pentad. Rikus is the gladiator slave who leads a revolt, kills the Sorcerer-King of the city-state of Tyr, and ends up going to the desert and eventually battling Borys the dragon.