# A Fantasy trilogy whose main cast consisted mostly of half-breeds

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recall the name of a sword-and-sorcery fantasy trilogy which I've read about 20 years ago. The things I remember are:

- The plot was set mainly in a desert-wasteland area, and many of the characters were half-breeds.
- The Elves in that setting were tribal wildlings. They were very tall, above 2m on average, and they excelled at extremely long distance running.
- One of the main characters was a human who could read minds. The process of mind reading was thoroughly described: When someone`s mind was being read, sometimes he could become aware of it - and the mind reader had to "escape" its victim's mind as quick as possible.
- Another important character was an exceptionally strong Half-Dwarf (Dwarf/Human). He was bald and beardless as I recall, and I think he was a gladiator or a slave.
- One of the main characters was half-Elf who grew up in an urban area. She joined a tribe of Elves at some point, and struggled at keeping the pace with them.

Comment: @Otis, no it isn't. The question in the attached link may describe a story set the Dark Sun world, but it isn't part of Prism Pentad series (or at least not part of the first 3 books in the series which I was asking about).

Comment: Fair enough. To be clear: The main point of my comment was to link related posts for the benefit of future searchers, not to criticize . I'll change it to a "see also."

Comment: see also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93338/looking-for-a-book-about-a-slave-that-gathers-friends-and-goes-into-a-desert-to for other books in this same series and universe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This could be the [Prism Pentad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dark_Sun_novels), a series of [five books](http://darksun.wikia.com/wiki/Prism_Pentad) by Troy Denning, based upon the Dark Sun Setting for AD&D Second Edition.

The main protagonists are a *mul* (a dwarf/human half breed), a half elf mage and a human and a half-giant. They have adventures in a desert fantasy setting. The universe they live in is big on psionics, in part because arcane magic damages the already fragile ecosystem.

Comment: Yep, this is it! Thank you. I've been thinking about this book lately for some unknown reason... Though not sure if at 32 I'll enjoy reading them as much as I did when I was 13, if at all.

Comment: @:Fingolfin: I liked them a lot, too, and I think they are still some of the better D&D-fiction books out there.

Comment: @Rorschachhamster - You have my +1 and an acceptance from the OP. Well done. You might want to clean up the obsolete comments now.